# Get hovered link using jQuery

Tags: jquery, hover, mousehover

Hy there!

Is there any way to determine which  element is currently hovered (by mouse) using jQuery?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific?  At any given time many elements are "hovered", any parent of the element you're on is also "hovered"...so what exactly are you after? :)

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation for .mouseover().

[JQuery API MouseOver](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/)

Answer (score 0):

yes it is:

```
$("div.hover").hover( //select the elements you want to check the hover on, in this case i check all divs with the class hover
   function(){ $(this).dosomething() },
   function(){ $(this).dosomethingelse() }
)
```

`$(this)` is the element that is acually hovered
here is an example that shows you how it works:
http://jsfiddle.net/hwhe7/

the second example makes an array of all elements you have hovered on your body:
http://jsfiddle.net/mdH7L/